# My brother is three times as old as me. How many times my age now was his age when I was born?

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

> My brother is three times as old as me. How many times my age now was
> his age when I was born?

It is a question invented as a puzzle for kids (!) by Igor Vladimirovich Arnold (1900-1948). I am not a kid anymore and am having a lot of difficulty in solving it. I am confused now. I guess it's because I was never exposed to this kind of question (I dunno). It's for kids, so it should be simple, but the wording does a knot in my brain somehow.

Comment: It can help to try an example. Suppose you're 8 years old, which makes your brother 24. That means that when you were born, your brother was 16. Now, "How many times my age now (8) was his age when I was born (16)?" In other words, $8$ times what is $16$? For this example, the answer is $2$. Is that always the case?

Comment: This is a typical crosswords puzzle. Call $k$ your age now and $x$ your brother's age now. You know $\frac xk=3$ and you want to know $\frac{x-k}k$, id est $\frac xk-1=2$.

Comment: If you are referring to [this Igor Vladimirovich Arnold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Arnold) you got his birth and death dates wrong or work in a different calendar. Please clarify.

Comment: I think Igor Vladimirovich Arnold is the father of Vladimir Igorevich Arnold. They have very similar names. So people may confuse them sometimes.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry for the confusion on my side.

Comment: If your age now is $x$, the brother's age now is $3x$ and when you were born it was $3x-x=2x$

Comment: "This is a typical crosswords puzzle."  Does "crossword" mean in your native language what it does in English? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossword)

Comment: @fleablood Yes, but I've used it as a metonymy for "puzzle magazine".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $b$ denote the age of your brother, and $m$ denote your age.  Your brother is 3 times as old as you, so
$$b = 3m.$$

When you were born, your brother's age was
$$b' = b-m.$$

So,
$$\frac{b'}{m} = \frac{b-m}{m} = 3-1 = \bf{2}.$$

Your brother's age when you were born is twice your age now.